# Just thinking about clients and things to do create anxiety

Tags: working-from-home, freelance

I know it's easy to say just relax or go exercise, but what I'm noticing is that there's so many things to keep track of as a freelancer and sometimes one just pops up in my head and distracts me and creates anxiety/stress. I'm even having stomach cramps from time to time possibly due to this.

Things like:

- Remember to follow up
- Organize tax documents/forms
- Reply to a client
- Send invoice
- Keeping track of feedback and requirements

The thing with freelancing is that clients contact at scattered times throughout the day. I may wake up in the morning and see an email to address, and I may be enjoying my night when I check my email and see a new message.

It's just difficult to get my mind off of freelancing and all the clients' demands and all the emails that need replying, etc.

Comment: It looks like an observation. What is your question here?

Comment: Maintain a TO DO list and stop being anxious.

Answer (score 1):

I think improving your time management will help. The overarching theme is organizing and structure.

Try getting a (used) book on time management. It will probably cover topics like:

- Eisenhauer principle
- ABC analysis
- ToDo vs. calendar entries
- Reserving time slots
- etc.

After a little practice you‘ll stop being triggered by each and every Email or call. Don‘t forget: clients contact you, because you have something to offer.

**P.S.**:

> It's just difficult to get my mind off of freelancing ... and all the
> emails that need replying, etc.

May be raising your charges/price a little bit helps clearing the field as needed?

- those sensitive to price only steel your time anyway
- at the correct balance the increase in revenue at least compensates fewer clients

Just some extra thoughts.